# Select values from dropdown on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box as in below. Below code is just part of my whole page. It looks like in the image [image: Please find the drop down Day field]

**Now I want it such that when user types in 8 from keyboard, 8 is selected. If user types in 9, 9 is selected etc.** How to do this?

js fiddle link is at http://jsfiddle.net/gQ5zV/ . **It needs to be cross browser compatible with IE 7 if possible.**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label for="custom3" class="col-sm-12 control-label myDate">Date marked on your receipt (dd/mm/yyyy)*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" name="custom3" id="custom3">

            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
          </select>        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <select class="form-control" name="custom4" id="custom4">
            <option value="1">January</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <select class="form-control" name="custom5" id="custom5">
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="errorDate col-sm-12"></div>
      </div></div>
```

Comment: Can you not use <option value="08">8</option><option value="09">9</option> ?

Comment: Well that solved for 8 and 9.. How about for 10-30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is over complicated.

Change `<option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option>`

To `<option value="08">8</option><option value="09">9</option>`

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Z5DDW/

For 15, user hits 1+5 on their keyboards.  Doing this on Windows using latest versions of Chrome, FF and IE9.

Comment: @Himu the 8 and 9 key press doesn't work or the number '1' follow by the number '5' for 15?

Comment: the number '1' follow by the number '5' for 15 does not work. Using latest firefox/chrome etc

Comment: Windows.. Actually if I press quickly it seems to work but a bit buggy. hmm I will take it working :) Just dont have the energy to look more on this on Friday for this

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your dropdown isn't changing when you click 8 or 9, is because you have the zero before it. If you had 8 or 9 in the value it would work.

With jQuery you could fire a keypress event and change the value based on which key they pressed.

```
$('.form-control').on('keypress', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

   // the keycode for the number 8 is 56
   if (code == 56){
       $(this).val('08')
   }

});
```

Comment: When you're looking for more than one key it becomes more difficult. Because you have to look for the keypress for 1 followed by 0. The previous example of native functionality of a lot of browsers for 1+0 keypresses is definitely valid. If you want to use jQuery then you'll have to log the keypresses.

Comment: hmm so that javacript solution won't work for my problem